# MySql WHERE LIKE before particular character?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have to search for a particular word from two columns but in one column I have to search before * character. so I used `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 'Enable' AND topic LIKE '%car%' OR category LIKE '%car%'` now the problem is it's returning beauty column also because it's category column has the word **car**e, now I have to make it if the word contains before the first * it has to return.

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| topic  | category                                                                  | status  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| car    | cars & vechicles*cars*                                                    | Enabled |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| beauty | Fashion, Health & Beauty*Health and Beauty Products*Body Care / Skin Care | Enabled |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Sounds like "before the frist *" is a solution very specific to the data you have right now. What if you have "Care & Beauty" as a category in the future? Or "Oscar winning movies"? Do you not prefer to look for car or cars as a whole word?

Comment: Also, read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: if it has "Care & Beauty" before first * no problem.. it can return the results

Comment: So maybe consider storing everything after the * in a different column? There is a solution for what you want with Regex (see the link I posted), but if there's a special meaning to the text before the first *, maybe it should be stored separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should solve your problems:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
status = 'Enable' AND topic LIKE '%car%' OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(category,'*',1) LIKE '%car%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple modification to your query by adding "%*" like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 'Enable' AND topic LIKE '%car%' OR category LIKE '%car%*%'
```

Comment: This would not work as expected for the category: `Fashion, Health & Beauty*Body Care / Skin Care*something`. It does not address the request to look only before the **first** *